# How to use ippsFFTInit_C_64fc?

Tags: c++, intel-ipp

my code is like this:

```
#include \<stdio.h\>
\#include "ipp.h"

int main(){
int specSize = 0, bufferSize = 0, specBufferSize = 0;
int order = 12;
IppStatus status = ippsFFTGetSize_C_64fc(order,IPP_FFT_DIV_INV_BY_N,ippAlgHintNone,&specSize,&specBufferSize,&bufferSize);

    IppsFFTSpec_C_64fc* spec = (IppsFFTSpec_C_64fc*)ippsMalloc_64fc(specSize);
    Ipp8u* pSpecBuffer = (Ipp8u*)ippsMalloc_8u(specBufferSize);
    Ipp8u* pBuffer = (Ipp8u*)ippsMalloc_8u(bufferSize);
    
    status = ippsFFTInit_C_64fc(&spec,order,IPP_FFT_DIV_INV_BY_N,ippAlgHintNone,pSpecBuffer,pBuffer);
    
    ippsFree(spec);
    ippsFree(pSpecBuffer);
    ippsFree(pBuffer);

}
```

The return result of `ippsFFTInit_C_64fc` is normal, which means `status==0`. However, when it comes to `ippsFree`, a segmentation fault occurs:
`\*\*\* Error in './IPPTest': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000000890630 \*\*\*`

How should I fix this?

I found that when `order` is less than 11, the code works. What's more, if I deleted all `ippFree`, the code still works even when order is larger than 11. Therefore, I believe that this is not caused by insufficient memory space.

Comment: Hi- I notice a few problems: you shouldn't allocate (or free) spec, also you're passing the wrong buffers to ippsFFTInit_C_64fc(), pSpecBuffer should be sized specSized, pBuffer should be sized specBufferSize, and you should handle the value of status (if it's not zero- so you know if your order is valid).